# Android facebook hash key invalid and does not match

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I know that it already discussed many times but i can not resolve it from last 6 hours .

[screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuuT2l.png)

[image]

i have generate hash key using

```
 try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "integrate.social.arifhasnat.facebooklogindemo",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));

            System.out.println(Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

But every time it shows same error . Can anybody help me ,please ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the shown key in screenshot to facebook developer console. It will work fine.
[image: The key shown in it]